# jQuery popBox plugin: it accumulates event time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Due to my poor English, let me use example to explain my problem.
1, Go to http://jsfiddle.net/27xV2/1/ 
2, Open firebug and go to console tab. 
3, select any text at Result grid then it'll popup a box and click either Apply or Cancel button. 
4, You'll see 1 in the console of firebug. 
5, Repeat step 3, you'll see 2 1, 3 2 1.

jQuery popBox plugin has been modified a little bit for my needs and the original one is at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/popBox , however, which works the same way.

I'm working on a project that must ensure the mouseup event only works once when it is activated.

I have spent 2 hours in this, however, I don't have any clue. How can I solve this problem?

Thx in advance,
Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching the `click` events **within** the `mouseup` event. Which means that they're attached every time the `mouseup` event is fired. Move them outside and it should work.

On a side note: You're once calling `attr('Id')` and the next time `attr('id')`.